# error with a function to retrieve data from a database

Tags: r, bioinformatics, ncbi

I am trying to get a FASTA file form NCBI website, I use the following function

```
getncbiseq <- function(accession){
  dbs <- c()
  for (i in 1:numdbs){
    db <- dbs[i]
    choosebank(db)
    resquery <- try(query(".tmpquery", paste("AC=", accession)),silent = TRUE)
    if (!(inherits(resquery, "try-error"))){
      queryname <- "query2"
      thequery <- paste("AC=",accession,sep="")
      query(`queryname`,`thequery`)
      # see if a sequence was retrieved:
      seq <- getSequence(query2$req[[1]])
      closebank()
      return(seq)
    }
    closebank()
  }
  print(paste("ERROR: accession",accession,"was not found"))
}
```

When I try to retrieve the sequence

```
mydata <- getncbiseq("NC_001477")
```

> Error in getSequence(query2$req[[1]]) : object 'query2' not found

Is there a better way to shorten these loop function also ?

if I use

```
query('queryname','the query')
#or 
query("queryname","thequery")
```

I get another error

> Error in query("queryname", "thequery") : 
>     invalid request:"unknown list at (^): \"(^)thequery\""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you intended to assign your call to `query()` to a variable called `query2`, but you forgot to do it.  Try this:

```
if (!(inherits(resquery, "try-error"))) {
  queryname <- "query2"
  thequery <- paste("AC=", accession, sep="")
  query2 <- query(queryname, thequery)
  # see if a sequence was retrieved:
  seq <- getSequence(query2$req[[1]])
  closebank()
  return(seq)
}
```

As you mentioned, the rest of your code also has some quirks and kinks which could probably be improved upon.

**Update:**

Here is a refactor of your code using `sapply` on the `dbs` vector instead of an explicit for loop (the latter which is usually frowned upon by R people):

```
processdbs <- function(x, y) {
    choosebank(x)
    resquery <- try(query(".tmpquery", paste("AC=", y)), silent = TRUE)
    if (!(inherits(resquery, "try-error"))) {
      queryname <- "query2"
      thequery  <- paste("AC=", y, sep="")
      query2 <- query(queryname, thequery)

      # see if a sequence was retrieved:
      seq <- getSequence(query2$req[[1]])
      closebank()
      return(seq)
    }
    closebank()
}

getncbiseq <- function(accession) {
   dbs <- c("genbank","refseq","refseqViruses","bacterial")
   result <- sapply(dbs, processdbs, y=accession)
   closebank()

   print(paste("ERROR: accession",accession,"was not found"))
}
```

You may have to do a slight amount of additional work to inspect the `result` vector and determine whether a sequence was retrieved anywhere.

Comment: that is perfect Tim, it works, do you know by any chance a way to shorten the loop ? if no, no problem I liked and accepted your answer anyway

Comment: I don't know if it can be shortened, but you could instead use an `apply()` function on the `dbs` vector, and eliminate the explicit loop completely.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for great help. I was stuck at this point for a full day. I finally got the following code worked under windows 10 with R3.4.0(32bits):-

```
getncbiseq <- function(accession)
{
require("seqinr") # this function requires the SeqinR R package
# first find which ACNUC database the accession is stored in:
dbs <- c("genbank","refseq","refseqViruses","bacterial")
numdbs <- length(dbs)
for (i in 1:numdbs)
{
db <- dbs[i]
choosebank(db)
# check if the sequence is in ACNUC database 'db':
resquery <- try(query(".tmpquery", paste("AC=", accession)), silent = TRUE)

if (!(inherits(resquery, "try-error"))) {
  queryname <- "query2"
  thequery <- paste("AC=", accession, sep="")
  query2 <- query(queryname, thequery)
  # see if a sequence was retrieved:
  seq <- getSequence(query2$req[[1]])
  closebank()
  return(seq)
}
closebank()
}
print(paste("ERROR: accession",accession,"was not found"))
}
```

Comment: Worked for me in R v3.3.3 on Ubuntu 16.04. Saved me a lot of hassle, cheers!

Comment: This worked for me in R v3.4.3 on Windows 7. Thanks.